# Nginx URL Encoding Issue

Tags: apache, nginx

I'm using Nginx in front of Apache and have an issue with URL encoding.

Requests for :

```
GET /forum/index.php%3Ftopic%3D14454.3775%3Bwap2
```

Produces this error in Apache (when proxy_passed from Nginx) :

```
/forum/index.php?topic=14454.3775;wap2' not found or unable to stat
```

When I request the url above (not encoded) it gets processed just fine.

The solution I found is I need to change:

```
proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:80;
```

to

```
proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:80/;
```

When the forward slash is excluded, the original request will not be decoded. When I add the forward slash, this is the error message I receive :

```
"proxy_pass" cannot have URI part in location given by regular expression, or inside named location, or inside "if" statement, or inside "limit_except" block
```

My nginx config block is :

```
location ~* ^/forum/index.php
{
    charset ISO-8859-1;
    include /etc/nginx/proxypass.conf;
    proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:80;
}
```

How can I fix the proxy_pass directive and include the forward slash so the request url is decoded before it's passed over to Apache?

EDIT:

Request:

```
GET /index.php HTTP/1.1" 200 16481 "http://www.example.com/forum/index.php%3Ftopic%3D14454.3775%3Bwap2
```

Error:

```
script '/www/example.com/httpdocs/forum/index.php?topic=14454.3775;wap2' not found or unable to stat
```

Comment: Try `proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:80$request_uri;` if that doesn't work then try `proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:80/$request_uri;` and see if any of them works

Comment: Unfortunately, they did not work. The url is still not decoded and throws a 404 error.

Comment: Can you check in logs what was sent?

Comment: I've updated my post to show the request and the error message I am receiving.

Comment: This almost solves the issue : http://127.0.0.1:80/$uri?$args; - however, the ";wap2" in the URL is ignored.

Comment: `~*` means a path regexp in the `location`, though looks like a simple prefix one. Do you really need the regexp?

Comment: Without it, the URL gets picked up by a different location block (that handles .html files) and throws a 404 error - http://www.example.com/forum/index.php/topic,48036.0.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve the issue by doing this.

If there is a better way to handle this, please let me know.

```
location ~* /forum/index.php(.*)
{
    include /nginx/proxypass.conf;
    if ($args) {
        proxy_pass  http://127.0.0.1:80/forum/index.php?$args;
    }
    proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:80/forum/index.php$1;
}
```